# In emacs' sql-mode, how can I connect to a SQL DB through a proxy or gateway?

Tags: sql, emacs, elisp

I'm branching out into using emacs' `sql-mode` to work with some databases at my job. Some of these databases are not accessible directly from my workstation - I need to ssh to a gateway server before I can connect to them (i.e., `mysql -h 'foo_host' -u 'foo_user' --password='double_foo' -D foo_db` works in a terminal session on the gateway server, but doesn't work when run directly on my machine). I searched around EmacsWiki and the Customize interface for `sql-mode` a bit, but I can't find a built in way to say "for connections to the Foo database, you need to use host Bar as a proxy." Is there a way to tell `sql-mode` to do this, or am I limited to hacking it by making an `~/.ssh/config` entry with a foo-db-specific name and an appropriate ProxyCommand invocation?

Comment: If you create an SSH tunnel on localhost that forwards localhost:13337 to foo_host:appropriate_port, does SQL mode allow you to connect to foo_db on using port fowarding?

Comment: Pretty sure it does (will test), but that's the same SSH workaround with a different moustache.

Comment: Ah, I missed the last sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is.  But it should be fairly easy to hack sql.el
in order to support this (by introducing a new connection parameter
`sql-remote').  In the meantime you have to switch manually somehow to
the `directory' of the gateway, e.g. with

```
M-x cd /ssh:gateway.com: RET
```

or from lisp

```
(let ((default-directory "/ssh:gateway.com:"))
  (sql-connect "ssh-hop-connection"))
```

Comment: Accepting because although I don't like that "nope, can't do that" is the answer, it appears to be the correct and definitive answer.